# How do I write an Application Test that tests that when a button is pressed, a particular view is shown?

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, xcode4

I'm looking at apple's [example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneUnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html) for application tests, and it all involves changes within a particular view.  I'd like to write a test which asserts the following:

```
Given that I am seeing the Results view,
And I press the button for the first result,
Then I should see a Detail view,
And its controller's result property should be set to the first result
```

How would I go about writing that test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also look at the an open-source integration testing framework which has been published by the good people over at Square.  Looks like it could help you automate some if the UI-level interaction tests that you seem to be interested in.

I haven't used this framework myself, but have been meaning to check it out.

http://corner.squareup.com/2011/07/ios-integration-testing.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In pseudocode, I think your test would go like this:

```
// in setUp, grab a reference to your desired view controllers & buttons
// in the test method:
//   press a tab (or whatever it takes) to navigate to the Results view
//   press the button for the first result (using target/action or however you have it set up)
     STAssertTrue([myNavigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]]);
     STAssertTrue([(DetailViewController *)myNavigationController.visibleViewController result] == /*first result from earlier*/);
// in tearDown, do cleanup if necessary
```

If this isn't enough, you should post some of your code so we can help more easily.

---

Edit: Further info about `setUp`. I think it's worth looking at the implementation from the sample code you linked to:

```
- (void) setUp {
   app_delegate         = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   calc_view_controller = app_delegate.calcViewController;
   calc_view            = calc_view_controller.view;
}
```

`app_delegate`, `calc_view_controller`, and `calc_view` are instance variables of the `CalcApplicationTests` class, so they can be used from within any `-test...` method. The app delegate, by nature of being the controller for the app, has a reference to the main view controller. I think this is a pretty simple and sane way of doing it.

Comment: I haven't any code to post, yet - but that's very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Could you add a bit of detail about how I'd grab the references to the controllers?

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with this either, but I'll edit in a little more info about that.

Comment: Thanks!  KIF turns out to be a good way of doing the things you describe... shame I can't split the bounty two ways.